# "invalid email address" parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a sign up with parse, and I'm pretty sure I did it right. However, whenever I put in values in the text fields and press the button nothing happens and I just get an error in the console saying:

```
2015-09-27 19:30:45.203 ParseStarterProject-Swift[42538:6770189][Error]: invalid email address (Code: 125, Version: 1.8.5)
Optional("invalid email address")  



//register in to app
@IBAction func register(sender: UIButton) {



    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = username.text
    user.password = username.text
    user.email = username.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String
            print("\(errorString)")
        }else{
            print("success")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Might be helpful to print() the email address to the console (before you send it into parse) to see if it was correctly formed.

Comment: OMG I FOUND TEH ISSUE LOL

Answer (score 1):

that might be leading you to invalid credentials

```
user.password = username.text
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same challenge, only to realize that I created two outlets from my user text field: one for username, and another for email.

Once I corrected this error (by selecting one text field for username, and the text field for email), it worked just fine.